# Fontes não funcionam no Safari/ Firefox

Tags: html, css

opa, boa noite.

desenvolvi meu site, porém a família tipográfica que usei no site não aparece no navegador Safari e Firefox, ao invés da Nunito é outra... E é uma fonte do Google Fonts, se alguém puder ajudar, tentei usar o @fontface porém não deu, não sei se usei da maneira correta, sou iniciante é meu primeiro site se alguém conseguir ajudar.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:ital,wght@0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap");

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.body {
  font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
}

/* menu */
#navbar {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 105px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: -10px 0px 20px #00000007;
  height: 100vh;
  right: 0;
}
#navbar-item {
  margin-top: 40vh;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.chama-text {
  font-family: nunito-extrabold;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  padding-left: 55px;
}
.chama {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.whats {
  padding: 0px 15px 0;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.linkedin {
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

/* texto principal*/
#showcase {
  background-color: white;
  height: 100vh; /* aqui 100vh para ocupar toda tela*/
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

#showcase-container {
  text-align: center;
}
#showcase-container h1 {
  margin-bottom: 64px;
  height: 364px;
  font-family: nunito-semibold;
  font-size: 302px;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.ponto {
  color: #00ff6c;
}
.foto {
  top: 222px;
  left: 1135px;
  width: 274px;
  height: 364px;
}
#showcase-container .apresentacao {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 800px;
  font-family: nunito-extralight;
  font-size: 32px;
}
.box-apres {
  font-family: nunito-bold;
  background-color: #00ff6c;
}

.candido {
  font-family: nunito-bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="footer.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:ital,wght@0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>portfólio do cândido</title>

</head>

<body>
  <nav id="navbar">
    <ul id="navbar-item">
      <li class="chama-text">CHAMA</li>
      <li class="chama"><img src="/img/arrow.svg" alt="chama"></li>
      <li class="whats"><a href="https://wa.me/5551995796592" target="_blank"><img src="/img/whats.svg" alt="whats"></a></li>
      <li class="linkedin"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/c%C3%A2ndido-mantovani-9a018219b"> <img src="/img/linkedin.svg" alt="linkedin"></a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <header id="showcase">
    <div id="showcase-container">
      <h1>olá<span class="ponto">.</span> <img class="foto" src="/img/ca.png" alt="can"></h1>
      <p class="apresentacao">meu nome é <span class="candido">cândido</span>, aqui estão alguns dos meus <span class="box-apres">projetos</span>, você pode conferir eles logo abaixo
      </p>
    </div>
  </header>
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que o problema é o uso de `nunito-semibold` e `nunito-extralight`, que não são nomes reconhecidos da fonte. O font-family deve ser sempre "Nunito". Se quer que fique semibold, defina `font-weight: 600`, e para extralight use `font-weight: 200` (acho que seria 100, mas seu import do google fonts não está incluindo esse peso, começa no 200).